# How to use DateTimePicker to SetSystemTime?

Tags: c#, winforms, compact-framework, datetimepicker

It is probably simple, but I don't see a [DateTimePicker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.aspx) property or method that I can use to [SetSystemTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa450867.aspx) in Microsoft Visual Studio Microsoft.NET WinForms CompactFramework v2.0 Windows CE 5.0.

Edit: more specifically, how to I get the selected date out of [DateTimePicker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.aspx) so I can apply it to [SetSystemTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa450867.aspx)?

Comment: You need pinvoke, visit pinvoke.net for the declarations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the following snippet should work:

```
[DllImport("coredll.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool SetSystemTime(ref SYSTEMTIME time);

[StructLayoutAttribute(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct SYSTEMTIME
{
    public short wYear;
    public short wMonth;
    public short wDayOfWeek;
    public short wDay;
    public short wHour;
    public short wMinute;
    public short wSecond;
    public short wMilliseconds;

    public SYSTEMTIME(DateTime value)
    {
        wYear = value.Year;
        wMonth = value.Month;
        wDayOfWeek = value.DayOfWeek;
        wDay = value.Day;
        wHour = value.Hour;
        wMinute = value.Minute;
        wSecond = value.Second;
        wMilliseconds = value.Milliseconds;
    }
}

public void setTimeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // DateTimePicker usually provide with the date but not time information
    // so we need to get the current time
    TimeSpan currentSystemTime = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
    DateTime newDate = newDateTimePicker.Value.Date;
    // Join the date and time parts
    DateTime newDateTime = newDate.Add(currentSystemTime);

    SYSTEMTIME newSystemTime = new SYSTEMTIME(newDateTime);
    if (!SetSystemTime(newSystemTime))
        Debug.WriteLine("Error setting system time.");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Maby this will help: http://codekingdom.blogspot.com/2008/10/how-to-set-device-clock-set-system-time.html

And this also: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/116676/Windows-Mobile-SetSystemTime-and-DST-Einstein-s-Re.aspx